# Klocwork Analysis Metrics Issue not Clear

Tags: c, metrics, klocwork

I don't understand this issue:

Issue: HIS Metriken - Cyclomatic (CR-MET4): [function_name] 13>10

It appears in Klocwork analysis while checking the issues of Code: METRICS.E.HIS_Metriken___Cyclomatic__CR_MET4_

Can anyone support?

Thanks

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and study the concept of making an [mre]. Without that information it is pure luck that this question turned out actually answerable.

Comment: Just for fun, allow me to try my clairvoyance a little more. Are you working in automotive industry, with contact to German car manufacturers or German tier 1 suppliers to those manufacturers?

Answer (score 1):

Do you see all those `if`s, `else`s, loops in that function?
Those are the problem, you need to either design this function's logic more elegantly or split it into more functions with well-defined purposes.

By the way, I can only see that problematic function of yours because I am especially clairvoyant. For this kind of question you should normally show your code, just to be fair towards all those other users which cannot read your mind like I did.

Naaa, not really. The cyclomatic complexity is a measure for number of potential paths through your function. And that you have crossed the treshold of 10 by 3 means your function must be full of control structs, which create many paths.